# Classifying quadratic forms and their corresponding symmetrical matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

In my textbook it is written that a quadratic form $$Q(x) = x^{T}Ax$$is positive definite if and only if the eigenvalues of the symmetrical matrix A are all positive, negative definite if and only if the eigenvalues are all negative and indefintie if the eigenvalues are both negative and positive.
Is there any connection to the eigenvalues of the matrix A if the quadratic form is positive semidefinite or negative semidefinite?

Comment: Yes, it's the connection you are probably thinking about: the eigenvalues are nonnegative/nonpositive.

Comment: Usually the definition of "positive-definite" says nothing about eigenvalues, but says that if for all vectors $x\ne0$ you have $x^TAx>0,$ then $A$ is positive-definite. Are you sure that what your book said was referred to as a _definition_ rather than a theorem (or "proposition" or "lemma" or the like)?

Comment: Thank you, it was a theorem, I have corrected the question now